# Route issue with multi-auth in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to have both my frontend and backend on the same Laravel app. Basically if you append /admin to the URL you will have access to the backend. I have a Backend folder for my backend controllers and a Frontend folder for my frontend controllers. Inside each of them, I have duplicated the complete Auth controllers and changed namespaces and view accordingly.

Auth from backend works perfectly. But from the frontend, the "login" route goes to the backend login, which should not happen.

My web.php file :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('front.auth.login');
})->name('site_home');


Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('site_home');
});
```

The other file I've created for backend routes (which is called backend.php)

```
Auth::routes();

Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'is_admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('home');
});
```

And finally in RouteServiceProvide.php I have this function to map routes :

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Front')
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

    Route::middleware('web')
        ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Back')
        ->prefix('admin')
        ->group(base_path('routes/backend.php'));
}
```

I guess there is some conflict between the auth routes, so my first thought is that both route files are loaded and I would like only one of them to be loaded, depending of the context (having admin in the URL or not). I tried several solutions based on multi-auth issues but they didn't help to solve my issue, sometimes messing a bit with the admin routes becoming admin/admin.

I already used Laravel a bit but to me this is going a bit off the beaten track. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'But from the frontend, the "login" route goes to the backend login'? When you visit '/' is it taking you somewhere else, or is the problem after posting credentials you are being redirected to backend?

Comment: if you run `php artisan route:list` do you have different routes for your front and back Auth?

Comment: @Bryan visiting '/' is okay, and there I have my front login form. The submit URL (generated from {{route}}) is /admin/login instead of login/

Comment: @HamzStramGram I have indeed admin/login and login and both are named login. So here is the issue, same name so the first one is used. Thanks it helps!